# How to set a value to a specific component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game using reactjs. I have a function named `setSquareValue` to set the value of squares to `X` but when I am clicking on a **square** all the other squares also filling with `X`.

The hierarchy is `Game.js -> Board.js -> Square.js`. I am using `useState()` which is in `Game.js` and also the function `setSquareValue` is in `Game.js`. I am passign the function to `Square.js` through `Board.js`.

Here is my codes:
**Game.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Game.css'
import Board from './Board';

const Game = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const setSquareValue = () => {
    setValue("X")
  }
  return (
    <div className='game'>
      <h1 style={{color: "#fff"}}>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      <h4 style={{color: "#2D033B"}}>Winner: </h4>
      <Board value={value} setSquareValue={setSquareValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

**Board.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Square from "./Square";
import "./Board.css";

const Board = ({ value, setSquareValue }) => {
  const squareKeys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  return (
    <div className="board">
      {squareKeys.map(squareKey => (
        <Square 
        key={squareKey} 
        value={value} 
        setSquareValue={setSquareValue} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

**Square.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Square.css";

const Square = ({ value, setSquareValue }) => {
  return (
    <div className="square" onClick={() => setSquareValue()}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Square;
```

I want, when I click a certain square, only that square fill with `X`. But every square is filling with `X`. How can I solve this?

I tried but `X` is appearing in every box of the game.

***Edited: Added CSS codes***

**Game.css**

```
.game {
  background-color: #AD7BE9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Board.css**

```
.board {
  background-color: #645CBB;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

**Square.css**

```
.square {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your styles also?

Comment: Added the css @DecPK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the value to every single square in your map function, for the solution you can move your `value` state and `setSquareValue` function to square component so that every square itself has its own value.

**updated Square.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Square.css";

const Square = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const setSquareValue = () => {
    setValue("X")
  }
  return (
    <div className="square" onClick={setSquareValue}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Square;
```

also you don't need to pass `value` and `setSquareValue` from Game.js to Board.js and Square.js anymore;

Comment: No need of creating an anonymous function instead what you can do is to pass function reference directly to `onClick` as `onClick={setSquareValue}`. Not a big deal but just FYI

Comment: @DecPK Yes, I just copied his code, I will edit it thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a unique state for all of the square in `Game` component. so if you change any time all of the square state will change so this problem occurs. So what you can do is instead of common state, you can create an individual state in `Square` component as:

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-forest-94yku4?file=/src/App.js)

```
const Square = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const setSquareValue = () => {
    setValue("X");
  };
  return (
    <div className="square" onClick={setSquareValue}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you are tracking `value`. Move the logic to store the `value` state from `Game.js` to `Square.js`

When your app begins, there is one instance of `Game` which has an initial value set to `value`. Then you pass this single value to `Board`, where it renders that same value 9 times. Likewise, when you change that single value, it gets changed in `Game`, then passed to `Board`, then finally rendered 9 times.

Let `Square` store its own state.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using only one state variable for all square:
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

You can declare as array variable that length is 9 for 9 square.

**Game.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Game.css'
import Board from './Board';

const Game = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(Array(9).fill(''));
  const setSquareValue = (index) => {
    let values = [...value];
    values[index] = 'X';
    setValue(values);
  }
  return (
    <div className='game'>
      <h1 style={{color: "#fff"}}>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      <h4 style={{color: "#2D033B"}}>Winner: </h4>
      <Board value={value} setSquareValue={setSquareValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

**Board.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Square from "./Square";
import "./Board.css";

const Board = ({ value, setSquareValue }) => {
  const squareKeys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  return (
    <div className="board">
      {squareKeys.map((squareKey, index) => (
        <Square 
        key={squareKey} 
        value={value[index]}
        ind = {index}
        setSquareValue={setSquareValue} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

**Square.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Square.css";

const Square = ({ value, ind, setSquareValue }) => {
  return (
    <div className="square" onClick={() => setSquareValue(ind)}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Square;
```